# SignalR 0.5.2 - Context.User is null on disconnect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I recently updated to SignalR 0.5.2 from 0.4.0 in my ASP.NET MVC3 application. In SignalR 0.5.2 the "User" property on the Context instance is `null` when the user disconnects - is this by design?

As seen from the "Immediate Window" snapshot below, all I know about the `Context` when a client disconnects is the disconnecting client's ConnectionId.

```
Context
{SignalR.Hubs.HubCallerContext}
    ConnectionId: "... some connection id ..."
    Headers: null
    QueryString: null
    RequestCookies: null
    ServerVariables: null
    User: null
```

Simplified, my SignalR `Hub` implementation looks like this:

```
public class MyHub : Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected
{
    // some other code

    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        var user = Context.User; // <-- This is null
        // more code
    }
}
```

To sum up - am I forgetting something here or is it by design that Context.User is `null`? And if so - why? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in the SignalR wiki. In its section about hubs ( https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs ) it states:

> Whenever a client disconnects, the Disconnect method will be invoked on all hubs that implement IDisconnect. When this method is called you can use Context.ConnectionId to access the client that disconnected.
>   **NOTE: This method is called from the server, that means state on the Caller object, any state that was with the connection, as well as the HubContext's User and Cookies will not be populated.**